# Is onResume() called after intent finished?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is the method in MainActivity called after intent (which was called from MainActivity) is finished?

By intent was finished I mean: MainActivity creates intent to open another activity, and when you are done in that activity you go back to MainActivity, is the onResume method called?

Comment: what do you mean by 'intent was finished'?

Comment: Yes, after returning from second activity to first activity  Onresume() of first actvity will be called

Comment: yes it is. The life cycle of activity is well explained in the documentation page for `Activity`

Comment: Thank you. I just did not get it from that picture I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onResume()` is triggered when the app loses focus, and then gains focus back again.

So yes, the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 6):

For others, the full process (in this case) would be:

```
1. MainActivity.onCreate()
2. MainActivity.onStart()
3. MainActivity.onResume()
4. startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class))
5. MainActivity.onPause()    // when partially obstructed
6. SecondActivity.onCreate()
7. SecondActivity.onStart()
8. SecondActivity.onResume()
9. MainActivity.onStop()     // when fully obstructed
```